# VBA paste data into the next row

Tags: excel, vba

I do not use VBA much but need to complete this task. I cannot figure out how to paste data from entry form into the Log spreadsheet. Here what I have so far.

It works. The only problem is it overrides what is there in the Log.

```
Sub RangeCopy_Transpose()

  
    Dim shRead As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Set shRead = Sheets("Log")
  
    Range("B3, B5, B7, B9, B11, B13, B15, B17,B19,B21,B23,B25").Copy
    shRead.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    
    Range("B3:B26").ClearContents
    
End Sub
```

Comment: [Find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost near. You need to find last data entry cell on sheet `Log` `Column A`. Then paste data to next empty cell. Try below sub.

```
Sub RangeCopy_Transpose()
Dim shRead As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

    Set shRead = Sheets("Log")
    
    'Detect last row with data.
    lastrow = shRead.Cells(shRead.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Range("B3, B5, B7, B9, B11, B13, B15, B17, B19, B21, B23, B25").Copy
    shRead.Range("A" & lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True 'Lastrow+1 will paste next cell from last data cell.
    
    Range("B3:B26").ClearContents
    
End Sub
```